# Android Camera.open

Tags: android, исключения, камера

Проблемы при запуске приложения 
Вылетает exception "Failed to connect to camera service"
Падает на Camera.open()

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnClickListener, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Camera.AutoFocusCallback
{
    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView preview;
    private Button shotBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // если хотим, чтобы приложение постоянно имело портретную ориентацию
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        // если хотим, чтобы приложение было полноэкранным
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // и без заголовка
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // наше SurfaceView имеет имя SurfaceView01
        preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);

        surfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        // кнопка имеет имя Button01
        shotBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        shotBtn.setText("Shot");
        shotBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        if (camera != null)
        {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;

        int previewSurfaceWidth = preview.getWidth();
        int previewSurfaceHeight = preview.getHeight();

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = preview.getLayoutParams();

        // здесь корректируем размер отображаемого preview, чтобы не было искажений

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            // портретный вид
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            lp.height = previewSurfaceHeight;
            lp.width = (int) (previewSurfaceHeight / aspect);
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            // ландшафтный
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            lp.width = previewSurfaceWidth;
            lp.height = (int) (previewSurfaceWidth / aspect);
        }

        preview.setLayoutParams(lp);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == shotBtn)
        {
            // либо делаем снимок непосредственно здесь
            //  либо включаем обработчик автофокуса

            //camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
            camera.autoFocus(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        // сохраняем полученные jpg в папке /sdcard/CameraExample/
        // имя файла - System.currentTimeMillis()

        try
        {
            File saveDir = new File("/sdcard/CameraExample/");

            if (!saveDir.exists())
            {
                saveDir.mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/CameraExample/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            os.write(paramArrayOfByte);
            os.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        // после того, как снимок сделан, показ превью отключается. необходимо включить его
        paramCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean paramBoolean, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        if (paramBoolean)
        {
            // если удалось сфокусироваться, делаем снимок
            paramCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        // здесь можно обрабатывать изображение, показываемое в preview
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.laboratory_8">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, стектрейс исключения

Comment: Судя по коду активити, разрешение камеры не запрашивается, только объявляется в манифесте. Однако разрешение камеры необходимо запрашивать у пользователя так же - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: @nikialeksey А что делать, если TakePhoto failed?

Comment: Мало информации, может TakePhoto failed в другой вопрос оформить? Приложить стектрейс тоже

Comment: @nikialeksey https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025224/android-camera-takephoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Судя по коду активити, разрешение камеры не запрашивается, только объявляется в манифесте. Однако разрешение камеры необходимо запрашивать у пользователя так же - developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Да, это верно

Добавил код. Все заработало

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Permission is not granted
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
        } else {
            // No explanation needed; request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
    }
```