# Android camera.takePhoto

Tags: android, камера, android-camera

Проблема с методом takePhoto. При вызове метода происходит Exception
"takePhoto failed"

```
E/Camera: Error 2
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.laboratory_8, PID: 7629
    java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1564)
        at com.example.laboratory_8.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:140)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Исходный код

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnClickListener, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Camera.AutoFocusCallback {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 42;
    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView preview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
        }


        // если хотим, чтобы приложение постоянно имело портретную ориентацию
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        // если хотим, чтобы приложение было полноэкранным
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // и без заголовка
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // наше SurfaceView имеет имя SurfaceView01
        preview = findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);
        preview.setOnClickListener(this);

        surfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;

        int previewSurfaceWidth = preview.getWidth();
        int previewSurfaceHeight = preview.getHeight();

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = preview.getLayoutParams();

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        lp.width = previewSurfaceWidth;
        lp.height = (int) (previewSurfaceWidth / aspect);

        preview.setLayoutParams(lp);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == preview) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera) {
        try {
            File saveDir = new File("/sdcard/CameraExample/");

            if (!saveDir.exists()) {
                saveDir.mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/CameraExample/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            os.write(paramArrayOfByte);
            os.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        paramCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean paramBoolean, Camera paramCamera) {
        if (paramBoolean) {
            paramCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera) {
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.laboratory_8">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая ошибка может возникать, если `takePicture` вызывается несколько раз подряд. То есть нужно убедиться, что колбэк по сохранению изображения завершился, и только потом можно делать следующий `takePicture`. Я бы добавил флаг:

```java
    private boolean takePictureAvailable = true; // <---

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == preview && takePictureAvailable) { // <---
            camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
            takePictureAvailable = false; // <---
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera) {
        try {
            File saveDir = new File("/sdcard/CameraExample/");

            if (!saveDir.exists()) {
                saveDir.mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/CameraExample/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            os.write(paramArrayOfByte);
            os.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        paramCamera.startPreview();
        takePictureAvailable = true; // <---
    }
```

Comment: Да, все верно)
Странные ошибки... Запустил на реальном устройстве заработало идеально